# Zend_Form_Element_Hash изменить message

Tags: php, zend-framework, form

Господа и дамы, коллеги, помогите разобраться. Имеем в форме следующий элемент:

```
$token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('csrf_token');
$token->setSalt(md5(microtime() . uniqid()));
```

Как у него поменять сообщения об ошибке, он выводит "The two given tokens do not match". Я уже и в самих классах Zend полазил, ни чего не нашел. По сути это обычный валидатор срабатывает, но как мне изменить это сообщение об ошибке на свое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было просто сделать:

```
$token = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('csrf_token');
$token->setSalt(md5(microtime() . uniqid()));
$token->getValidator('Identical')->setMessages(array(
        Zend_Validate_Identical::MISSING_TOKEN => 'Обнаружена попытка CSRF-атаки. Перезагрузите форму.',
        Zend_Validate_Identical::NOT_SAME => 'Обнаружена попытка CSRF-атаки. Перезагрузите форму.'
    ));
```